# Tar cannot expand subfolders from .tar archive

Tags: bash, permissions, tar, subdirectory, archive

I'm trying to expand tarball native archive (not a Gzipped version) from bash script using separate commands for a reason.

Tar archive format:

```
File1
File2
folder1/file3
folder1/file4
```

Then i execute next commands:

```
tar xvf archive.tar -C $TEMP_DIR/ File1
tar xvf archive.tar -C $TEMP_DIR/ File2
```

Both succesful

Next I execute separate commands for file 3 and 4:

```
tar xvf archive.tar -C $TEMP_DIR/ folder1/file3
tar xvf archive.tar -C $TEMP_DIR/ folder1/file4
```

Both fails for:

```
Tar: folder: Permission denied
Tar: file: No such file or directory
```

Please advise!

Comment: Do the errors really have `Tar` (capital T) and `folder` / `file` (rather than `folder1` and `file3` or `file4`) ?

Comment: Most likely answer is that `TEMP_DIR` is not set during second set of commands. If you replace `tar` by `echo` what does it print? Which implementation of tar are you using (and what OS)?

Comment: @jhnc No, I used that as "short" form for original tar and files names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure archive.tar is in the correct place,
Following script reproduce the whole process :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mkdir -p /tmp/{dest,src/folder1}
cd /tmp/src
touch File{1,2} folder1/file{3,4}

tar cvf ../archive.tar *

TEMP_DIR=/tmp/dest

cd /tmp
tar xvf archive.tar -C $TEMP_DIR/ File{1,2}
ls  -l $TEMP_DIR
read -pEnter
tar xvf archive.tar -C $TEMP_DIR/ folder1/file{3,4}
ls  -l $TEMP_DIR/folder1
```